# Remove Spaces between between characters and numbers in a string

Tags: mysql

I am trying to remove spaces between characters and numbers in a string 
For example if I have "Value 01", I want "Value01" back . So I wrote a function, but it is giving me error Unexpected ), Also I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it. I tried searching for Regex Replace but couldn't find anything as such

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `RemoveSpaces`(
   myWord VARCHAR(1000)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)

BEGIN
DECLARE RETURNSTRING VARCHAR(1000);

SET RETURNSTRING = (
SELECT 
   LEAST (
   if (Locate('0',myWord) >0, 
      REPLACE(myWord, ' 0', '0'),
   if (Locate('1',myWord) >0,
      REPLACE(myWord, ' 1', '1'),
   if (Locate('2',myWord) >0,
      REPLACE(myWord, ' 2', '2'),
   if (Locate('3',myWord) >0,
      REPLACE(myWord, ' 3', '3'),
   if (Locate('4',myWord) >0,
      REPLACE(myWord, ' 4', '4'),
   if (Locate('5',myWord) >0,
      REPLACE(myWord, ' 5', '5'),
   if (Locate('6',myWord) >0,
      REPLACE(myWord, ' 6', '6'),
   if (Locate('7',myWord) >0,
      REPLACE(myWord, ' 7', '7'),
   if (Locate('8',myWord) >0,
      REPLACE(myWord, ' 8', '8'),
   if (Locate('9',myWord) >0,
      REPLACE(myWord, ' 9', '9')
   )
 )
);
RETURN RETURNSTRING;
END
```

Comment: include the error message next time please but jherran is correct

Comment: @Noah, I mentioned this in my post, "but it is giving me error Unexpected ),"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a function for that. Just use `REPLACE` in your query:

```
SELECT REPLACE("This is a string", " ", "") FROM dual;
```

And will return `Thisisastring`.

Comment: How can I do the opposite of it, for example I have "Value01", I need "Value 01".

Comment: You can use something like this: `select INSERT("Thisstring01", LEAST (if (Locate('0',"Thisstring01") >0,Locate('0',"Thisstring01"),999), if (Locate('1',"Thisstring01") >0,Locate('1',"Thisstring01"),999), ... if (Locate('9',"Thisstring01") >0,Locate('9',"Thisstring01"),999)
  )-1 ,1," ") from dual;`

Comment: Replace `...` with `if (Locate('1',"Thisstring01") >0,Locate('1',"Thisstring01"),999),` from `2` to `8`. Keep in mind that you should ask another question in this cases.